# Genesys WDE detect offhook c#

Tags: c#, platform-sdk, genesys

I'm trying to detect offhook/answered a call on Genesys WDE. I download WDE and platform SDK and trying to play wit tserver events. Documentation is not so clear to me, so if someone can point me in the right direction I will appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to subscribe to the events handlers. The following code works for calls:

```
container.Resolve<IAgent>.FirstMediaVoice.Channel.Protocol.Received += YourEventHandler;
```

You must subscribe them in the Login event as per Genesys support team.